# How to change textual data into neumerical data in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-query-language

I am relatively very new to the google sheets and excel, there is a task I need to perform. 
I have a google form, that is taking user response and storing Data in a google sheet, the values are textual verbiage and I want to change this to corresponding numerical data. 
What I have tried so far is, I have created a new sheet and with the help of query function I am storing this data into a different sheet, Is there a way to write a query function in a way, with the help of IF statements where it converts the data into numerical values.

[image: Data stored in google sheet]

The query I am using to fill the data in the next sheet.

```
=QUERY('Form responses 1'!A1:AF)
```

Is there a way where I can modify this query and get the result like this in the next sheet?

where value of "you slightly feel this way." should convert to 1
and value of "you somewhat feel this way (and somewhat not)." should convert to 2

or what is the other way to achieve the same result if not the queries?

Comment: Why tag excel if you are using google sheets?

Comment: Why not simply use an **IF formula** to do the same? Are these the only 2 statements that you need to convert?

Comment: I would, in excel, use a lookup() table to convert from text to number or vice versa - depends on how many items though.

Comment: HI @Gangula If I am using IF formula with the query it is giving me error "An array value could not be found" Below is the formula I am trying to use in the cell A1
=QUERY('Form responses 1'!A1:AF, IF(('Form responses 1'!C2:AF = "you slightly feel this way"),3))

Comment: That's not how the query formula works @Saurabh. and I did not mean to add the IF formula within the query. You can simply use the IF formula in a different adjacent column.

Comment: Thanks @Gangula, I appreciate your help, as I just started learning this I was in confusion If I can do any such thing with the query, appreciate your answer

Comment: Any suggestion about how we can achieve this.

Comment: @Saurabh, Unfortunately Query doesn't allow changing/restructuring text values. You need to do this in a different column.